# Metrics for Cosmos read regions

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We've set up a cosmos account in North Europe with Geo replication to West Europe. Consistency is set to "Session"(Default). The intent is to use North Europe as a single write region and both regions as read. This is because the requirements are to have no performance degradation during batch data ingestion data into the database. We are using ADF to do the batch ingestion.
The question I have is how do I monitor the metrics for the read only region? When I look at the Metrics on Cosmos, I can only still see North Europe in the drop down.
[image]

Comment: I think it comes from lacking of the operations in West Europe, I tested in my side and post details below. If you feel it meaningful, could you pls mark it as the answer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any progress sir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks. So this is not a problem.
I found that when you create a write region and 1 or more read regions, the other regions metrics will not be visible until there is some metrics to report. The replication of data does not contribute to the Metrics/throughput usage.
To test this, I wrote some python code to fetch some data and set the secondary read region as the preferred location. Just 2 minutes after executing the code, the read region appeared on the Metrics region drop down.
The python code I used to define the client is below :

```
client = CosmosClient(ENDPOINT, {'masterKey': MASTER_KEY}, preferred_locations = ['Central US'])
```

[image]
[image]

Am closing this question.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason. `other regions metrics will not be visible until there is some metrics to report`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem also appeared in my side.

I have a test db which set east-asia as write only and other regions read. When I reached metrics page, only east-asia in the drop down of region filter. I guess it comes from the location of the operation(all my operations are from this region so there only provides the only one choice). After I delete the east-asia region in `Replicate data globally` and did some query, then I can see another region in metrics.

I also tested in my another database, it doesn't enable global distribute and I haven't use the database for a long time. When I opened the metric page, I find it provides no choice for region. But after execute a query and wait for a while, the region showed in drop down.

[image]
[image]